# terraform aws ec2 ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have this terraform script:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-weast-1"
}


resource "aws_security_group" "allow_all" {
  name        = "allow_all"
  description = "Allow all inbound traffic"


  ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 0
    protocol        = "-1"
    cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  vpc_id = "vpc-154c1701"

}


resource "aws_instance" "wso2-testing" {
  ami           = "ami-0f9cf087c1f27d9b1"
  instance_type = "t2.small"
  key_name = "mykeypair"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.allow_all.id}"]

    }
```

The machine is created correctly, but i can´t connect to ec2 instance using my key pair with ssh.
Always i have the error:

```
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Operation timed out
```

The VPC es aws default with internet gateway

Comment: what is your operating system?

Comment: Ubuntu, i connect using ssh -i my_key_pair_path ubuntu@public_ip

Comment: Make a folder on desktop copy your pem file.now again goto folder , Do right click and run in terminal. you can see folder name and run this command. chmod 400 yourkey.pem. then run ssh -i ubuntu@youraws

Comment: start watching this video from 30:00 min https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0g1M5bb9u4     you will definitely get your answer

Comment: at once watch whole video you will get all your answer.

Comment: I have correct permission for my pem file 0400, the video is so much instructive thank you, but i think i have a vpc problem or something similar for expose the ssh port.

Comment: It should be protocol = "all" or protocol = -1 to make all ports open.
(Please note this is not a security best practice)

Comment: @PubuduJayawardana I am clear of the security flaw, but after trying to open only port 22 without success, I decided to open all ports, just as unsuccessfully.

Comment: Did you try with  protocol = "all"  as well? To be honest, I don't see any error in the script if id values are correct

Comment: did you set inbound rules? port 22 @mleaf

Comment: Your security group has a VPC-ID but your instance does not. Is this private IP or public IP instance. My recommendation is to remove the VPC from the instance or assign the default VPC to both. The issue could be your VPC, Subnet, NACLs, ...

Comment: There's also a typo in your `provider "aws"` block: `us-weast-1` should be `us-west-1`

Comment: I use the @victorm recomendation, now works. thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can add your own IP to security group using below snippet:

```
data "http" "myip"{
    url = "https://ipv4.icanhazip.com"
}

ingress {
        # TCP (change to whatever ports you need)
        from_port   = 0
        to_port     = 0
        protocol    = "-1"
        # Please restrict your ingress to only necessary IPs and ports.
        # Opening to 0.0.0.0/0 can lead to security vulnerabilities.
        cidr_blocks = ["${chomp(data.http.myip.body)}/32"]
      }

egress {
        # Outbound traffic is set to all
        from_port       = 0
        to_port         = 0
        protocol        = "-1"
        cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your own IP into inbound rule of your security group.
Check my blog or git sample
https://sv-technical.blogspot.com/2019/12/terraform.html
https://github.com/svermaji/terraform

HTH